# Right way of requesting storage permission in android 6

Tags: android, permissions

While requesting storage permissions in android 6, Is it better to -

1) ask for both `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` and `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` through activity?

2) specify both  `android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` and `android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` in manifest?

I noticed that by requesting only read permission, the storage permissions toggle button gets toggled, so technically I am getting both by asking for just one.

Answer (score 1):

You always have to request permissions through the manifest. Whether you *also* have to request them via `requestPermissions()` depends on OS version and your `targetSdkVersion`.

> I noticed that by requesting only read permission, the storage permissions toggle button gets toggled, so technically I am getting both by asking for just one.

At present, while we request *permissions*, users grant *permission groups*. That may change in the future.